# how to solve nonlinear system of equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have $A, B, C, D, E, F.$ I want to calculate a and b from the following system of equations:

[image: system of equations]

I know I should solve this system using $3$ equations and $3$ unknowns, but it is not linear.

can any one show me how to solve it?

**Edit:** We know that $a>=b>=0$ and $tetta$ is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $A+C=a^2+b^2$, that $A-C=\left(b^2-a^2\right)\,\cos(2\Theta)$, and that $B=\left(b^2-a^2\right)\,\sin(2\Theta)$.  Hence, $\left(b^2-a^2\right)^2=(A-C)^2+B^2$.  You only need to solve for $a^2$ and $b^2$ from $a^2+b^2=A+C$ and $a^2-b^2=\pm\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}$.

If $\Theta$ is an unknown, then there are $8$ possible values of $(a,b)$ (due to signs of $a$, of $b$, and of $a^2-b^2$).  If $\Theta$ is known, then as mathreadler said, there are $4$ possible values of $(a,b)$.

Comment: Yes good observation, I did not think of that $\theta$ could be unknown.

Comment: It is unclear from the question what are known and what are not.

Comment: I added the knowns & unknowns in the edit. I figured that $a = sqrt((A+C +- sqrt((A-C)^2 + B^2))/2)$ and $b = sqrt((A+C-a))$. but the results are not correct. I tested them in wolfram alpha.

Comment: Why should your results be correct when $b\neq\sqrt{(A+C)-a}$?

Comment: sorry i missed a power. $b = sqrt(A+C - a^2)$. but the result is incorrect

Comment: You will have to take $a^2-b^2=\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}$ if you are to assume that $a\geq b\geq0$.  Also, you maybe should learn how to use LaTeX.  It's quite a nuisance to see $sqrt$, $tetta$, or $>=$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find $a^2$ and $b^2$ from line 1 and 3. Then you just need to find the sign of a and b, only 4 combinations to try. Of course you need to check that the other equations are not being violated by the solution you find.